# Casting gives me wrong date?

Tags: sql-server, casting

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) AS TRANSACTION_YEAR, DATEPART(MONTH, PURCHASE_DATE) AS TRANSACTION_MONTH,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE) >= DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE)
ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) END AS RELEASE_YEAR, 
CASE WHEN (DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) AND DATEPART(MONTH, DUE_DATE) >= DATEPART(MONTH, PURCHASE_DATE)) THEN DATEPART(MONTH, DUE_DATE)
WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE) > DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) THEN DATEPART(MONTH, DUE_DATE)
ELSE
DATEPART(MONTH, PURCHASE_DATE) END AS RELEASE_MONTH,
CAST(YEAR(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE) >= DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE)
ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) END) AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0'+CAST(MONTH(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) AND DATEPART(MONTH, DUE_DATE) >= DATEPART(MONTH, PURCHASE_DATE)) THEN DATEPART(MONTH, DUE_DATE)
WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, DUE_DATE) > DATEPART(YEAR, PURCHASE_DATE) THEN DATEPART(MONTH, DUE_DATE)
ELSE
DATEPART(MONTH, PURCHASE_DATE) END) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
FROM TEST
```

on a sample table of six records generates

```
2012    1   2012    1   190501
2012    1   2013    12  190501
2011    1   2012    1   190501
2011    1   2011    1   190501
2012    1   2012    1   190501
2012    1   2012    2   190501
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: That hurts my brain.  Please construct a simpler test-case!

Comment: I've guessed at SQL Server. If that's wrong, please edit your tags appropriately. You've shown is some output, but it's not clear what you're *trying* to achieve (you haven't told us). Also, what are the data types of the columns you're dealing with? Tell us *what* is wrong.

Comment: sorry, the fifth column is giving me the same output for each record and I don't know why?

Comment: Sample of input, expected output and remove columns that are correct, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to do it all in one go and repeating yourself all over the place.

If you start with

```
select 
DatePart(YEAR,PURCHASE_DATE) as PURCHASE_YEAR,
DatePart(YEAR,DUE_DATE) as DUE_YEAR,
DatePart(MONTH,PURCHASE_DATE) as PURCHASE_MONTH,
DatePart(MONTH,DUE_DATE) as DUE_MONTH
From Test
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT PURCHASE_Year AS TRANSACTION_YEAR, 
       PURCHASE_Month) AS TRANSACTION_MONTH,
       CASE 
       WHEN DUE_YEAR >= PURCHASE_YEAR THEN DUE_YEAR
       ELSE PURCHASE_YEAR
       END AS RELEASE_YEAR, 
       CASE 
       WHEN (DUE_YEAR = PURCHASE_YEAR) AND (DUE_MONTH >= PURCHASE_MONTH) THEN DUE_MONTH
       WHEN DUE_YEAR > PURCHASE_YEAR THEN DUE_MONTH
       ELSE PURCHASE_MONTH 
       END AS RELEASE_MONTH,
       CAST(
        CAST(RELEASE_YEAR As VarChar(4)) + 
        '-' + 
        CAST(RELEASE_MONTH as VarChar(2)) + 
        '-1' as DATE) as RELEASE_DATE
FROM (
select 
DatePart(YEAR,PURCHASE_DATE) as PURCHASE_YEAR,
DatePart(YEAR,DUE_DATE) as DUE_YEAR,
DatePart(MONTH,PURCHASE_DATE) as PURCHASE_MONTH,
DatePart(MONTH,DUE_DATE) as DUE_MONTH
From Test
) SomeDummyTableName
```

I think this is what you were after, and I may even have got it right after wading through that morass.

Comment: Thank you Tony but one of the limitations of the third party piece of software I am having to use is it has to be done in one go (and no work tables allowed either!)  Rubbish I know but I can only work with the tools I am given :-(  I DID suspect I was trying to achieve the impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're already extracting the month and year components using your `CASE` expressions - and passing the result of these expressions to the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions - which expect to be passed a `datetime` value. So, you're causing an implicit conversion of `int`s back into `datetime` values.

```
SELECT YEAR(2012)

----
1905

SELECT MONTH(12)

----
01
```

When an `int` is implicitly converted to a `datetime`, it's effectively the number of days since `19000101`. Most days ~2000 days beyond `19000101` occurred in 1905.

---

All this being said, this all looks a lot more complex than it needs to be - using a subquery, you could perform appropriate calculations once, rather than having to repeat them - what are the initial inputs, and the final output you're aiming for?

Comment: This has to be done in one query because I'm using a third party bit of software that has limited SQL functionality.  I have a simple test table of two columns (purchase date, due date) and six sample records.....I'm trying to get the release month (third and fourth columns of my output) into a fifth column in a YYYYMM format.

Comment: @RastaPickles, just done it for you I think, don't suppose I'm gonna get paid now huh :)